# Make a Flip animation (or something similar) when I reload the content of my UIWebView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwebview

In one of my project i'm using only a UIWebView. I need an animation (for example a flip) when I reload my webView with another content... Is it possible to create a flip animation (or something similar)? I must create a fake controller to get it?
Solutions?
Thanks

Comment: flip as in view doing a backflip or flip like a page curl?

Comment: like a page curl! sorry for the lapsus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you don't need to create a controller for that. You can simply add something like that:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.80];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:yourView cache:YES];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: WOW... That's what I was looking for... in yourView I have inserted my webView...(subclass) ;).

Comment: Is there a way to simulate the animation that do the PageController?

Comment: Do you mean like UIPageViewController? I don't know, but i think there is no way without using it.

Answer (score 3):

You can always do the `+transitionWithView:duration:options:animations:completion:` method with the web view.

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.webView duration:1.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionFlipFromLeft | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent animations:
^{
    [self.webView loadHTMLString:@"<strong>Hello world</strong>" baseURL:nil];
} completion:^(BOOL finished)
{

}];
```

This method is basically a way of saying: "change the contents of this view, in animated fashion". So it takes an snapshot of the current state, performs the animation (be it a flip, curl, etc) and then inserts an snapshot of the new state.

But notice that I've used `UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent`, this forces the animation to not use a snapshot for the new state of the view, because setting `loadHTMLString` does not change the view immediately, so we need to force it to use the live context of the view instead of a snapshot.

The weather app in iOS (pre 7) uses a similar method for alternating between the current weather and the picker for other regions/options when clicking the "i" on the bottom.

Comment: This option UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent was exactly what I needed. Otherwise the content of the web view changes only after the flip animation is complete.